# Concern about importing class implementation into DAO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have to implement DAOs which use only the interfaces of the objects. Now I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the `em.find()`of the `EntityManager`class.

My specific question is, if it is ok to import the implementation of a class directly into the DAO like in this example:

```
import dao.IStreamingServerDAO;
import model.IStreamingServer;
import model.impl.StreamingServer;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

public class StreamingServerDAO implements IStreamingServerDAO {

    protected EntityManager em;

    public StreamingServerDAO(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    public IStreamingServer findById(Long id) {
        return em.find(StreamingServer.class, id);
    }

}
```

I feel like I'm hurting some privacy principles by simply importing the `model.impl.StreamingServer` class into the DAO.

Problem is I don't know how else I'm supposed to get the needed class for the `em.find()`method.

Please not that I can't change the return type of the `findById`method as it's defined like this by the interface. (Also this implementation right now works as expected).

Comment: Yes, its valid. But Why is StreamingServer in impl package? As long as your using the POJO which represents database objects in DAO its fine.

Comment: In the `model` folder only the the interfaces are defined (like `I<Class>`) and in the `model.impl` folder all the classes are defined (like `<Class>`). Is this not standard or a thing you should not do? (In this project I'm not allowed to change the structure anyways)

Comment: Your assumption that the DAO should work with interfaces only is somewhat the culprit here. DAOs work with "EntityClasses" - in Java entity classes most of the time are simply POJOs - classes with fields, getters and setters. They do not have a common interface they implement.

Comment: Okay, as long as they're POJO's its fine to use them in DAO. Its just a little weird to have Interfaces to POJO's as well. Either ways, you're good to go.

Comment: Okay thanks, I have to use predefined Interfaces for all POJOs in this project. I also thought it was kinda wierd. And yes `StreamingServer`is a POJO.